# requestLocationUpdates five times started from IntentService

Tags: android, android-location, android-intentservice, android-googleapiclient

My control flow is in an `IntentService` (triggered by a GcmListenerService) and should now get the location of the user. As

```
LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient)
```

might return `null`, I should request some location updates. I assume with every update the location is more accurate than the one before because of GPS mechanics. I suppose five measurements/updates should be enough for an accurate location. 
How can I implement that logic in an `IntentService`? The class implements the listener interfaces:

```
public class LocationIntentService extends IntentService
 implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
 GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
 LocationListener
```

This way I could use a counter in `public void onLocationChanged(Location location)` and call `LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates()` after five updates. However, I'm not sure if I can trust Android that the same `IntentService` lives that long and is not removed by the garbage collector as soon as `onHandleIntent` is done.

This is the complete code I'm using so far without the logic to collect only five updates:

```
public class LocationIntentService extends IntentService implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {

    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    public LocationIntentService() {
        super("LocationIntentService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getBaseContext())
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();

        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
        System.out.println(result.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        LocationRequest mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(500);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {
    }

    private void displayLocation(Location location) {
        System.out.println(location.toString());
        DbHandler dbHandler = new DbHandler(getBaseContext());
        double latitude = location.getLatitude();
        double longitude = location.getLongitude();
        double altitude = location.getAltitude();
        float speed = location.getSpeed();
        long time = location.getTime();
        float accuracy = location.getAccuracy();
        PersistedLocation persistedLocation = new PersistedLocation(time, latitude, longitude, altitude, accuracy, speed);
        dbHandler.insertLocation(persistedLocation);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        displayLocation(location);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to accomplish this with `setNumUpdates(int i)` and `setExpirationDuration(long l)`.

```
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(500);
    mLocationRequest.setNumUpdates(5);
    mLocationRequest.setExpirationDuration(10000);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
    }
}
```